# What is the probability of getting a heart in $n$-th draw without replacement?

Tags: probability, card-games

> You are given a deck of cards. What is the probability of getting a heart at the first draw. What is the probability of getting the same in second draw without replacement? What is the probability of getting the same in $n$-th draw without replacement? Give explanation of your answer.

The probability of getting a heart in the first draw =$\dfrac{13}{52}=\dfrac14$

Using theorem of total probability the probability of getting a heart in the second draw =$\dfrac{13}{52}\times\dfrac{12}{51}+\dfrac{39}{52}\times \dfrac{13}{51}=\dfrac14$

So, intuitively the probability of getting a heart in $n-$th draw will be $\dfrac14$. But I am unable to give the explanation. Please help.

Comment: All sequences of $52$ cards are equally likely in a well-shuffled deck. The Queen of $\heartsuit$ is just as likely to be first as it is to be $17$-th, or last.  No calculation needed.

Comment: Is this assuming consecutive *heart* draws on the first through *n*-th draw (up to 13)? Or is it the probability of pulling a heart on the *n*-th draw given known probabilities for each of the previous draws?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Intuitively the probability is $\frac14$ as cards are equally likely. But I am looking for mathematical justification. I am thinking of difference equation and try to solve. But I am unable to construct difference equation.

Comment: @r2evans Consider the second draw. Then in the first draw we may get one heart or may not get one. But in the second draw we must have one heart.

Comment: The justification is perfectly mathematical.  The model we are using has all permutations equally likely.

Comment: I think the hardy proof of the $n$-th draw is impractical, but can you prove it by induction? That is, on the 2nd draw, you know $p=0.25$ because you can iterate through the two branches of the probability tree. On the 3rd, you have three branches (with $\frac{1}{16}$, $\frac{6}{16}$, and $\frac{9}{16}$ marginal probs), so you can still iterate through them. Is it safe (or just *weak inference*) to say that since the odds of the 3rd are the same irrespective of the state of the 2nd, then the $n$-th is irrespective of the state of the $(n-1)$-th?

Comment: Of course, $n \le 52.$ And a heart being the last card left still has probability 1/4. The definition of a well-shuffled deck is that all 52! permutations of the cards are equally likely.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that we put cards on the bottom of the deck after taking them from the top.  Then the $n^\text{th}$ card drawn is the top card, which we know has probability 1/4 of being a heart. (The point is that which card is considered to be the top one is arbitrary and meaningless, so it has no affect on the probability.)